# Errors and plugins not working when restoring a vim session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, youcompleteme

If I start fresh, and open several files related to my rails project, I am able to use gf, on say UserBidsDepot.new and it will open the appropriate file.  Also, autocomplete, via the YouCompleteMe plugin works as well.  Then I will create a vim session of my open files, tabs, etc:

`:mksession ~/VIM_SESSIONS/feature_userdepot.vim`

I am having two issues when I go to edit a previously saved vim session. When I restore the above saved sessions using:

`vim -S ~/VIM_SESSIONS/feature_userdepot.vim`

Then I see the following error:

**Error detected while processing VimEnter Auto commands for "*":
E117: Unknown function: youcompleteme#Enable
Press ENTER or type command to continue**

I can press enter to continue and all my files/tabs re-open to how I had them when I saved the session.  But, AutoComplete is not working and when I try to use gf, I get the following error:

**E345: Can't find file “user_bids_depot.rb" in path**

Exiting the session, and opening the same files without using a session, works fine.  So I'm assuming there is something on with mksession.

UPDATE: I have been able to work around the error for the YouCompleteMe plugin.  Instead of restoring a session by using vim -S session_name.vim, I first launch vim and restore the session using:

`:source ~/VIM_SESSIONS/feature_userdepot.vim`

However, I'm still having issues using the gf command in a restored vim session.